# How do you keep HTML tags when querying a xml using sql?

Tags: html, sql, xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to keep html tags in my sql query when i write a query to generate xml tags.
For example:

```
select '<p> this is a code</p>' as code
from table name
for xml path (''), type
```

outputs:

```
<code>&ltp&gt; this is a code &lt/p&gt; <code>
```

what it should output:

```
<code><p> this is a code </p><code>
```

How do I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: For XML Explicit I believe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947884/how-to-get-sql-query-to-not-escape-html-data-returned-in-query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using `xhtml`, I believe the conversion to `Xml` will do:

```
select convert(xml, '<p> this is a code</p>') as code
from table name
for xml path (''), type
```

EDIT: if the column is `ntext`, implicit conversion to `Xml` is supported:

```
create table #t(html ntext)
insert into #t values(N'<p> this is a code</p>')
select convert(xml, html) as code
from #t
for xml path (''), type
drop table #t
```

Comment: This works great but what if the variable you are converting is an ntext.

Comment: The conversion from `ntext` to `xml` is implicit (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)). I edited my answer to provide an example.

Comment: Thanks, the reason i asked about ntext was because the column i was trying to convert was ntext and i was getting an error. it turns out the variable contained a &, which is not so friendly with xml. Is there a way to parse &?

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to clean up the html before the conversion. You could use `REPLACE` to replace special characters with the characters entities. For example, for `&` you need `&amp;`, for `<` - `&lt;`, for `>` - `&gt;` etc. However, `REPLACE` doesn't work with `ntext` so you'll need to convert to `nvarchar`: `replace(convert(nvarchar(max), html), '&', '&amp;'))`

Answer (score 3):

below snippets works for me

```
DECLARE @HTMLt  NVARCHAR(MAX)  ;

........

SET @HTMLt = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@HTMLt,'&amp;','&' ) , '&lt;','<'),'&gt;','>');
```